# Query Multiple values for same key

Tags: meta-query

I have tried to get 2 different posts having the values in `$al`. I can retrieve the posts one at a time but fail to get both together:

```
$al = array('51.66963','51.60652');

$meta_query[] =  array(
  'meta_query' => array(
   'relation'  => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'estate_property_google_maps',
        'value'   => $al['0'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
),
  array(
      'key'       => 'estate_property_google_maps',
      'value'       => $al['1'],
      'compare'       => 'LIKE',
      ),
);
```

Comment: You have `key` three times in the second array and incorrectly closed arrays.

Comment: @birgire edited :)

Comment: What is the format of the data stored under the `estate_property_google_maps` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this ([doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query))?

```
$meta_query[] = array( 'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'estate_property_google_maps',
        'value'   => $al['0'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
      'key'       => 'estate_property_google_maps',
      'value'       => $al['1'],
      'compare'       => 'LIKE'
    ),
) );
```

Comment: fixed the problem :)